# Convert from VMDK to OVF

Tags: virtualization, xenserver, citrix, vmware-vmdk, ovf

How can I convert a VMDK to OVF?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The VMDK file is the actual virtual disk, an ovf file is just a settings file (plain text), that VMWare products (like ESXi Server) and other virtualization software (like Virtualbox) can use when importing the VM.

You may have an existing settings file (like a .vmx) which you can convert into ovf format using VMware's tool 'ovftool':
http://communities.vmware.com/community/vmtn/vsphere/automationtools/ovf

There's quite a lot of options, which are detailed here in the user guide:
http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/ovf/ovf20/ovftool_201_userguide.pdf

Comment: Example use: ovftool mymachine.vmx mymachine.ovf

Comment: BTW, ovftool's src and/or destination VM locations CAN be on remote ESX(i) hosts! :)

Comment: Haven't tried this yet but while importing into AWS I am guessing, its going to help me. I will post my findings when done

Answer (score 0):

You can use VMware's Workstation Pro or thier OVF tool.  In Workstation, load the VM then under file menu, select export to OVF.  Be aware this can take a long time.
VMware's OVF Tools is a command line option.